# Opposite brick of Brick, Modified 1 x 2 with Studs on 1 Side

Tags: piece-information

I was wondering if there was an opposite brick to [this one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=11211&name=Brick,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%20Studs%20on%201%20Side&category=%5BBrick,%20Modified%5D#T=P&C=86):

[image]

Basically, I am looking for a 1 x 2 brick with two holes on the side where I could join the brick mentioned above.

Comment: Hello and welcome Benoit. Can you tell me what you are trying to achieve with this? Since the combination of this brick and “the opposite brick” basically creates a 2x2 brick, why are you looking for a more complex solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best chances are with [Technic, Brick 1 x 2 with Holes](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32000). Although LEGO considers such connection illegal depending on application (see slides 2, 11 and 12 of [this presentation](http://bramlambrecht.com/tmp/jamieberard-brickstress-bf06.pdf) by Jamie Berard). However it works without major issues.

[image]

Comment: I can't care less if it's considered illegal :-). Thank you very much!